# Is cryotherapy contraindicated in sporting injuries or not?

Tags: cryotherapy, rice

RICE (Rest, Ice, Compression, Elevation) is a [standard procedure when dealing with sporting injuries](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27849130).

However, the "inventor" of said principle recently [discouraged longer cryotherapy.](https://web.archive.org/web/20140629055909/http://drmirkin.com/fitness/why-ice-delays-recovery.html) However, the literature regarding this is fairly in-concise. I am aware that RICE still is a recommended first aid strategy. How severe (if at all) is the contraindication of using cryotherapy?

Comment: Is anyone other than Dr. Mirkin saying there is a contraindication? His position in the article you cited seems a bit extreme.

Comment: @CareyGregory Someone claimed that cryotherapy might be contraindicated underneath a now-deleted post, and I was wondering what the literature is. I couldn’t find anyone else claiming that apart from Dr. Mirkin.

Comment: @CareyGregory there have been some admittedly poor studies recently questioning the efficacy of ice when treating acute injuries.